# Django on appegine and tutorial

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I am new to Django and Appengine. I found that Django 1.2 version is supported by Google Appengine. Does it mean that Django 1.2 comes with the installation of Google Appengine SDK?
Or should we install [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine)

Any pointers, experiences and tutorials on running Django on Appengine is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think djangoappengine would be a good start. It seems like an active project. Please also note that Google [offers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Google_Cloud_SQL) SQL backend as of October 2011 so whether you need SQL or NoSQL, you should be able to use Django for it.

**General note:** If you are new to both Django and GAE, you probably should start with learning Django on your local computer running a development server that comes with it. Once you get familiar with how Django works in general you can dig into GAE etc.

Comment: True, I already started learning Django and doing the exercises in Django book.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Django application without any/very less modifications on Appengine?

Comment: That's what django-nonrel is for as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), we use it professionally and it works well on App Engine.

Comment: Does django-nonrel works out of the box without any modifications for GoogleAppengine?

Comment: Yeah if you make use of [django-appengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) module, it should work out fine.

Comment: Thanks its promising. I am learning Django right now, i will try django-appengine. As you are using professionally, did you face any major gotchas with django-appengine?

Comment: The most important part is M2M relationships. You cannot use ManyToMany fields of Django on App Engine, you have to make use of [ListFields](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty) (and [djangotoolbox](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangotoolbox)).

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to start with this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/appengine_helper_for_django.html) as it is the official and recommended way for Django project on app engine.

Note that previously there some hacks and patches, but at the moment those are deprecated and above tutorial should be just enough to get you started.